# Count number of elements in bash array, where the name of the array is dynamic (i.e. stored in a variable)

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, parameter, shell-builtin

### Brief statement of the question:

Is there built-in bash method to count number of elements in bash array, where the name of the array is dynamic (i.e. stored in a variable), *without* resorting to making a fully copy of the array or using `eval`?

### More information:

Using bash parameter substitution, one can do the following:

- Determine the length of an array: 
  `myArr=(A B C); echo ${#myArr[@]}`.
- Indirectly reference a variable by name:
  `NAME=myVar;    echo ${!NAME}`
   (this also applies to array elements):
  `NAME=myArr[1]; echo ${!NAME}`

But if the name of an array is stored in another variable, how can one determine the number of elements in the array? (One might consider this a *combination* of the above two parameter substitutions.) For example:

```
myArr=(A B C D)
NAME=myArr
# Get the number of elements in the array indirectly referenced by NAME.
count=${#$NAME[@]}  # This syntax is invalid. What is the right way?
```

Below are multiple attempts that all FAIL:

```
  # Setup for following attempts:
  myArr=(A B C D)
  NAME=myArr
  EXPR1=$NAME[@]          # i.e. EXPR1='myArr[@]'
  EXPR2=#$NAME[@]         # i.e. EXPR2='#myArr[@]'

  # Failed attempts to get the lengh of the array indirectly:
  1.  count=${#$NAME[@]}  # ERROR: bash: ...: bad substitution
  2.  count=${#!EXPR1}    # ERROR: bash: !EXPR}: event not found
  3.  count=${#\!EXPR1}   # ERROR: bash: ...: bad substitution
  4.  count=${!#EXPR1}    # ERROR: bash: ...: bad substitution
  5.  count=${!EXPR2}     # Returns NULL
```

I've also tried some other variants of the above, but have not yet found anything that works without either: (A) making a copy of the array or (B) by using `eval`.

### Working Methods:

There are a couple ways of solving this that are probably not optimal (but correct me if I'm wrong):

#### Method 1: Copy the Array

Assign the array to another (statically-named) variable and get the number of elements in it.

```
EXPR=$NAME[@]
arrCopy=( "${!EXPR}" )
count=${#arrCopy}
```

#### Method 2: Use `eval`

```
EXPR="count=\${#$NAME[@]}"  # i.e. 'count=${myArr[@]}'
eval $EXPR
# Now count is set to the length of the array
```

### Summary:

Is there any built-in method (i.e. parameter substitution syntax) in bash to determine the length of an array indirectly? If not, what is the most efficient way to do this? I assume it is the `eval` method above, but are there security or performance issues with `eval`?

Comment: Ugh. Nested variables. I'd rethink whatever approach got me here than use nested variables. What's the actual problem here?

Comment: It's an interesting question. The only thing I would caution you against is assuming something has or does not have a performance issue. I found during pretty rigorous testing to optimize very large bash scripts that some bash builtins were terrible in terms of performance, in fact, by simply removing one start up test in a large script, that used what you might have expected to be efficient, ie, variable expansion, in fact, that single line slowed the entire execution down by about 10 to 20%. Test methods in big loops with timers, results may surprise you.

Comment: `bash` [namerefs?](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare). `declare -n ref=abc; abc=(A B C D); printf '%s\n' "${ref[@]}"`

Comment: @muru - This is just semantics, but the term "nested variables" relates more to bash before version 2. Bash v2 added a syntax for "indirect variable references". I'm just asking whether there is a specific syntax to get the length of an indirectly referenced array. I assume the bash authors wouldn't have gone to the effort of implementing variable indirection for scalars *and* arrays if it were not a requested, useful technique--not simply a hack warranting an immediate "Ugh", although I'm sure that's debatable.

Comment: @muru - There isn't necessarily an "actual problem" here. It's more a question about a language feature. But for example: you want to write a library of functions for various array operations (e.g. push, pop, search).  Such functions *could* be designed to accept the elements of the array as parameters and then write the new array elements to stdout. But that approach requires creation of a subshell, copying the array (as function arguments), and then copying the modified array to stdout--all potentially expensive operations. A faster method would be to pass the array to the function by name.

Comment: @ricovox All true. But neither arrays nor indirect references seem to be first class members of the bash syntax. Your own problem, and the inability to export arrays both show that. I wonder how zsh and ksh handle this, though.

Comment: @Lizardx - I totally agree with you. Part of the reason I was asking this instead of just using one of those other methods was to get some feedback about the performance of these methods. Thanks for pointing out that some bash built-ins can be slow--that's good to note.   Also, *Lizardx* is an awesome handle!

Comment: @1_CR - I didn't know about *namerefs* so thanks for pointing them out. I think they probably represent the best answer to my quesion.  I was hoping for something that was present in older versions of bash because I need to target several operating systems and some (like Mac OS X 10.10)  come with older versions of bash (e.g. 3.2.x.x).  But since I didn't say anything about that in my question, I'll accept your comment if you post it as an answer.

Comment: ricovox, if performance is actually a serious issue, I'd recommend doing the testing yourself. I have never seen any serious performance related data for bash, not saying it doesn't exist, just never seen it. I was astounded at what I discovered. It's helpful to have old hardware to run some tests, I did a lot of my testing on 200mhz machine, where that single line of code in a 10k+ line script changed the speed from > 12 seconds to about 10 seconds, if I remember right. It was a loop, but very small one. Testing on newer hardware is fine too, you just have to up the iterations of the test.

Comment: I did a bit of a benchmark: `time bash -c 'a=(1 a +); c=a; for ((i=0;i<100000;i++)); do eval "echo \${#$c[@]}"; done' > /dev/null`, and similarly with `e=$c[@]; d=("${!e}); echo ${#d[@]}` in the loop. The eval took about 90% of the time taken by copying. And I suppose that gap will only increase the larger the array and its elements are.

Comment: if performance matters to you, then you are using the *wrong* shell. still, the `array[index]` is a math expansion, and so you can just set `count` directly there.

Comment: [Indirection is not possible in combination with any parameter expansion whose modifier requires a prefix to the parameter name. Specifically, indirection isn't possible on the `${!var@}`, `${!var*}`, `${!var[@]}`, `${!var[*]}`, and `${#var}` forms. This means the `!` prefix can't be used to retrieve the indices of an array, the length of a string, or number of elements in an array indirectly](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection)

Answer (score 4):

you should handle that stuff in the index evals. and you can indirect *through* your indirection variable's indices if you make it an array.

```
a=(abc1 def2 ghi3 jkl4 mno5)
r=('a[c=${#a[@]}]' a\[i] a\[@])
for   i in   0 1 2 3 4 5
do    c=
      printf "<%s>\n" "${!r-${!r[i<c?1:2]}}"
      printf "\n\tindex is $i and count is $c\n\n"
done
```

---

```
<abc1>

    index is 0 and count is 5

<def2>

    index is 1 and count is 5

<ghi3>

    index is 2 and count is 5

<jkl4>

    index is 3 and count is 5

<mno5>

    index is 4 and count is 5

<abc1>
<def2>
<ghi3>
<jkl4>
<mno5>

    index is 5 and count is 5
```

Because `bash`'s indices are 0-based, the total count of array objects will always work out to one more than than the highest set index, and so:

```
c=
echo "${a[c=${#a[@]}]-this index is unset}" "$c"
```

---

```
this index is unset 5
```

...the parameter expands out to the default word if any is provided.

If one is not provided:

```
c=
${!r}
echo "$c"
```

---

```
5
```

...there's no harm done.

In the loop I track an `$i`ndex variable and check if it is at least as large as `$c`ount. When it is lesser I expand the `$r`eference var to `a[i]` because it is a valid index, but when it is equal or greater I expand the `$r`ef to the entire `$a`rray.

Here it is in a function:

```sh
ref_arr(){
    local    index=-1 count=
    local    ref=(   "$1[ count= \${#$1[@]}  ]"
                     "$1[ index ]"    "$1[ @ ]"
    )  &&    printf  "input array '%s' has '%d' members.\n" \
                     "$1"  "${!ref-${count:?invalid array name: "'$1'"}}"
    while    [ "$((index+=1))" -lt "$count"  ]
    do       printf  "$1[$index]  ==  '%s'\n"  "${!ref[1]}"
    done
}
some_array=(some "dumb
            stuff" 12345\'67890 "" \
          '$(kill my computer)')
ref_arr some_array
ref_arr '$(echo won'\''t work)'
```

---

```
input array 'some_array' has '5' members.
some_array[0]  ==  'some'
some_array[1]  ==  'dumb
                stuff'
some_array[2]  ==  '12345'67890'
some_array[3]  ==  ''
some_array[4]  ==  '$(kill my computer)'
bash: count: invalid array name: '$(echo won't work)'
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31430/discussion-between-ricovox-and-mikeserv).

Answer (score 0):

bash 4.3 namerefs are a godsend. However, you can do this:

```
$ myArr=(A B C D)
$ NAME=myArr
$ tmp="${NAME}[@]"
$ copy=( "${!tmp}" )
$ echo "${#copy[@]}"
4
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but your answer is what I already described under the section "Method 1: Copy the Array".  The question also specifically stated that the array length should be determined "without resorting to making a fully copy of the array", which is exactly what you did.