# Find number of elements in array that is referenced by a dynamically created name

Tags: bash, variable, array

I found a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242251/count-number-of-elements-in-bash-array-where-the-name-of-the-array-is-dynamic), but it does not seem to be identical, and none of the answers provide the output that I want. I have an array, for which I want to find how many elements it contains by accessing it using dynamically generated name.

```
declare -a array0=(2 4 2 5)  # contains 4 values
indx=0
Name="array$indx"            # create a name reference => array0

# I know how to obtain an indexed value by INDIRECT reference:
val0=${!Name[0]}
# I also know how to get array length using DIRECT name
len=${#array0[@]}
```

What I need is find the number of elements of the *array0* by referencing it using variable *Name*

```
len=${#!Name[@]}             # the syntax is incorrect
```

Any suggestions for implementation?

**EDIT:**
I was wrong about being able to access the array entries using this:

```
val0=${!Name[0]}
```

It only works for indx=0, so if I wanted to get other entries from the array, it simply returns an empty string:

```
val4=${!Name[4]}          #does not work
```

or

```
i=4
val4=${!Name[$i]}         # does not work
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval` explicitly, but don't overuse it:

```
eval "len=\${#$Name[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you - this works. Let's see if there are other ways to do it

Comment: No sure about the consequences of overusing "eval", but it seems to be working very well for finding the number of elements in the referenced array, as well as reading the specific element from array using `eval elem=\${$Name[$i]}`

Answer (score 4):

With `bash-4.3` or above, you can use namerefs:

```
a0=(a b c)
i=0
typeset -n Name="a$i"
echo "${#Name[@]}"
```

or you can always [use `eval`](/a/368401). In any case, don't be fooled into thinking using `bash` namerefs is *safer* than `eval`. Like for `eval`, you still need to make sure the content of `$Name` is a valid shell variable name. Values like `` x[`evil-command>&2`0] `` would still cause that `evil-command` to be executed when you expand `$Name` or `${#Name}`. Same applies to `${!var}`.

With `ksh93`, you could use multi-dimensional arrays instead:

```
a[0]=(a b c)
i=0
echo "${#a[i][@]}"
```

`zsh` has more consistent ways to combine its expansion operators:

```
a0=(a b c)
i=0
name=a$i
echo ${(P)#name}
```

(`P` for indirect parameter expansion).

Comment: Almost there. Could you, please, see my edit?

Comment: I cannot do "typeset", because I need variable Name to contain the string of the original array, i.e. "array0"

Comment: @Naz, then you can use `Name=a$i; typeset -n ref="$Name"; echo "${#ref[@]}"` or use `eval` or the other alternatives.