# bash loop associative array with variable array name

Tags: bash, associative-array

I have a lot of associative arrays and i want to use only 1 loop. select the array for loop by a given name

I want to select/build a part of the arrayname with a variable and than loop with that name, but it doesn't work.

Like in OUTPUT3 and OUTPUT4, but the syntax is wrong.

For output 3 i receive: "bash wrong substitution"

For output 4 i receive: "only the arrayname and 0"

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

declare -A a1 a2 a3

a1['1']="1-1V"

a2['1']="2-1V"
a2['2']="2-2V"

a3['1']="3-1V"
a3['2']="3-2V"
a3['3']="3-3V"

# 1 OUTPUT WORKS
for i in ${!a1[*]}
do
echo -e "$i : ${a1[$i]}"
done

# 2 OUTPUT WORKS
for i in ${!a2[*]}
do
echo -e "$i : ${a2[$i]}"
done

# 3 OUTPUT - WRONG SYNTAX
selectkey="3"
for i in ${!a$selectkey[@]}
do
echo -e "$i : ${a$selectkey[$i]}"
done

# 4 OUTPUT - WRONG SYNTAX
key="3"
aselect="a${key}[*]"
# THIS ECHO WORKS
echo -e "ARRAY: ${!aselect}"

for i in ${!aselect[@]}
do
echo -e "$i : ${aselect[$i]}"
done
```

**UPDATE**

The solution is `nameref` | `declare -n`

This works for me now:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

declare -A a1 a2 a3

a1['1']="1-1V"

a2['1']="2-1V"
a2['2']="2-2V"

a3['1']="3-1V"
a3['2']="3-2V"
a3['3']="3-3V"

varname="a3"
counter=1

declare -n refname=${varname}

for i in "${!refname[@]}"
do
echo -e "$counter ${refname[$counter]}"
counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

Comment: Please don't use CAPS for variable names in shell scripts. That is just asking for trouble.

Comment: ok i will edit the question

Comment: Oh no, don't edit for that! I was just giving some general advice. More importantly, please add some context here. You are just dumping some code with "it doesn't work" but you don't explain how it fails, how you use it, or what you really need to do. Are you [looking for namerefs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242251/)?

Comment: @terdon namerefs was the right idea thanks, i got it with declare -n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a "nameref": `declare -n a=b` makes variable `a` an alias for variable `b`.

```bash
# 3 OUTPUT - use a "nameref"
selectkey="3"
declare -n ary="a$selectkey"

for i in "${!ary[@]}"
do
    echo "$i : ${ary[$i]}"
done
```

outputs

```
3 : 3-3V
2 : 3-2V
1 : 3-1V
```

Associative arrays are inherently unordered.

For #4, you are using "indirect expansion" as described in [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), but you can't get to the array's indices with that technique.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` does not have multidimensional arrays. However, you can implement them with an associative array and key concatenation (`key1` and `key2` represented as the combined string `key1,key2`). Here are some examples.

Given your starting scenario,

```
declare -A a

a[1,1]='1-1V'
a[2,1]='2-1V' a[2,2]='2-2V'
a[3,1]='3-1V' a[3,2]='3-2V' a[3,3]='3-3V'
```

All `a[1,*]` values:

```
for i in $(printf "%s\n" "${!a[@]}" | awk -F, -vk='1' '$1==k {print $2}')
do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "$i" "${a[1,$i]}"
done
```

Output

```
1: 1-1V
```

All `a[*,2]` values:

```
for i in $(printf "%s\n" "${!a[@]}" | awk -F, -vk='2' '$2==k {print $1}')
do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "$i" "${a[$i,2]}"
done
```

Output

```
3: 3-2V
2: 2-2V
```

An alternative way of producing the set of keys:

```
for i in $(printf "%s\n" "${!a[@]}" | awk -F, -vk='1' '$2==k')
do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "$i" "${a[$i]}";
done
```

Output

```
1,1: 1-1V
3,1: 3-1V
2,1: 2-1V
```

Notice that in all cases the keys are not in numeric order. If this is required you could modify the `printf | awk` construct to pipe through `sort -n` (assuming numeric keys).

You can also generalise the `awk` construct so that you can specify the field number as well as the required key value. This would help with encapsulation, perhaps by hiding the key generation in a function

```
awk -F, -vfield=2 -vkey=1 '$field==key'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your indexes are numbers, you're likely better off using regular arrays rather than associative arrays. Both can be sparse, but regular arrays let you iterate over the keys in numerical order, while for associative arrays it's essentially random. (In other languages, you might need associative arrays to get a sparse array.) Compare:

```
$ declare -A a=([11]=a [22]=b [33]=c ) 
$ echo "${a[@]}"
b a c
$ declare -a b=([11]=a [22]=b [33]=c)
$ echo "${b[@]}"
a b c
```

Then again, if your indexes are numbers and the arrays are not sparse, you can use associative arrays to fake a two-dimensional array, and iterate over the indexes with a manual loop.

```
declare -A a
a[1,1]="1-1V"

a[2,1]="2-1V"
a[2,2]="2-2V"

a[3,1]="3-1V"
a[3,2]="3-2V"
a[3,3]="3-3V"

x=3
i=1
while [[ ${a[$x,$i]+set} == set ]]; do
    echo "${a[$x,$i]}"
    ((i++))
done
```

(Of course you could emulate a sparse array here by setting the "nonexisting" elements to some special value which you'd then ignore inside the loop.)

Ksh also actually supports two-dimensional arrays, or, well, at least nested lists:

```
a[1][1]="1-1V"

a[2][1]="2-1V"
a[2][2]="2-2V"

a[3][1]="3-1V"
a[3][2]="3-2V"
a[3][3]="3-3V"

x=3
for x in "${a[x][@]}"; do
    echo "$x"
done
```

though this doesn't work:

```
for x in "${a[@][1]}"; do
    echo "$x"
done
```

Though, needing complex data structures is also one of the situations where it might be useful to consider switching from the shells to some other programming language.

In any case, don't use `${!array[*]}`, or `${!array[@]}` (with or without the `!`), but `"${!array[@]}"` instead, as that's the only one that keeps values containing whitespace intact. Try e.g. `z=("foo bar" "zoom")` and then compare `for x in ${z[*]}; do echo $x; done` with the same using `"${z[*]}"` or `"${z[@]}"`.