# Passing arrays to bash functions

Tags: bash

How can I pass arrays as input to a bash function using nameref?  Have not found very specific information for doing this.

For instance I have an array `incl` which I want to pass to a function, which then returns `isufx`.

```
## Split INCL by field separator FS
for ext in "${incl[@]}"; do

  if [[ "$ext" == "PROGL" ]]; then
    isufx+=( --include=\*.{rc,el,c,f} )
    (( vb >= 2 )) && echo " ext: $ext"
    continue
  elif [[ "$ext" == "PEXTD" ]]; then
    isufx+=( --include=\*.{rc,el,c,f} )
    isufx+=( --include=\*.{cp,cpp,f90,f95,f03,f08} )
    (( vb >= 2 )) && echo " ext: $ext"
    continue
  elif [[ "$ext" == "TYPOG" ]]; then
    isufx+=( --include=\*.{org,texi,tex} )
    (( vb >= 2 )) && echo " ext: $ext"
    continue
  fi
```

Comment: Check if this helps and fit it to your needs https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732112/515538

Comment: do you have an example of what to adjust?

Comment: I need an example that is very specific about making a function that takes arrays.

Comment: The reason you haven't found much info on doing this is because most people who need to do such things know that shell (including bash or ksh or zsh) is not a good language for complex tasks - they use more appropriate languages instead, e.g. perl or python or C or almost any language that isn't shell.   Not only are other languages better suited to complex tasks, they often have functions or syntax or libraries that allow you to do things in a few lines of code that would takes dozens or hundreds of lines in shell.

Comment: e.g. most languages have one or more methods of passing a variable by reference (i.e. a pointer to the actual variable) rather than by value(s) in a variable (copies of the data).  this makes it easy to pass arrays (indexed or hashed) and even complex data structures or objects to functions/subroutines....and to return them as the result of a function.  pass by reference is also significantly faster than copying large blocks of data to and from functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fill_array()
  typeset -n _in="$1" _out="$2"
  typeset _ext
  for _ext in "${_in[@]}"; do
    case $_ext in
      (PEXTD) _out+=( '--include=*.'{cp,cpp,f90,f95,f03,f08} ) ;& # fall through
      (PROGL) _out+=( '--include=*.'{rc,el,c,f} ) ;;
      (TYPOG) _out+=( '--include=*.'{org,texi,tex} ) ;;
      (*) continue
    esac
    (( vb < 2 )) || printf>&2 ' ext: %s\n' "$_ext"
  done
}

fill_array incl isufx
```

Here also using a `case` statement which seems more appropriate than an `if` one.

We pass the *names* of two variables to that function. Inside the function `_in` is defined as a *nameref* to the variable whose name is passed in the first argument, and `_out` for the second.

Then, when `$_in` or `$_out` are referenced in the function, they are automatically translated to the referenced function.

We prefix variable names with `_` in the function to limit the risk of the function being called with variables that happen to be used in the function as in bash, contrary to ksh93 where the nameref feature comes from¹ or zsh², that wouldn't work as the implementation is much cruder.

---

<sup>¹ ksh is also where `typeset` comes from. The fact that `bash` copied that feature decades later but decided to call the command `declare` I find quite annoying. Thankfully, it also accepts `typeset` as an alias.</sup>

<sup>² namerefs as of writing are only available in the current development version.</sup>

Comment: Then the function would actually figure out that the arguments `$1`, `$2` are arrays.  Why using `typeset` rather than declare?  Passing arrays as input would not involve using `"${incl[@]}"` ?

Comment: When calling the function, are the arguments actually passed just by declaring them as `incl`, `isufx`,  rather than  `"${incl[@]}"`, `"${isufx[@]}"` ?

Comment: Have been trying to use `out=$( fill_array ary )` using  `printf '%s\0' "${_out[@]}"`, which is definitely problematic..

Comment: @Hovlar, in `fill_array incl isufx`, we pass two literal strings `incl` and `isufx` to the function. `typeset -n _in=incl _out=sufx` in there *bind* / *reference* the `_in` and `_out` variables to the variables by those names.

Comment: If you wanted the function to return the result as a NUL delimited list, first you wouldn't define `_out` as a nameref, then you couldn't use `printf` like that as it wouldn't work for empty lists (you'd need a `print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }`), and to read the result into an array, you'd need `readarray -td '' out < <(fill_array ary)` for which you need bash 4.4+.

Comment: Right.  You do not pass the actual variables, but their name.  Which get interpreted by the function internally.

Comment: Would `mapfile -d '' -t new_array < <( fill_array ary ) ` also be a possibility?  Which would be better ?

Comment: `mapfile` is another name for the `readarray` builtin, but it's a misnomer as it's just reading, not mapping. `readarray -td ''` is another way to write `readarray -d '' -t`.

Comment: Suppose that I have two different outputs, one named `pk` and another being `isufx`.  Noticed that `readarray -td '' pk < <(fill_array incl isufx)` does not produce output for `isufx` in addition to `pk`.

Comment: A related question is about whether returning an array as a `nameref` versus a `printf` return is good.  Using `printf '%s\0' "$ary3"` to return an array `ary3` seems to pose some difficulties.  Using `/0` does not seem to give good array processing behaviour.  Any comments about use of `printf` with arrays? I would tend to stick with `nameref` for anything involving arrays.

Comment: Passing the list NUL delimited means filling up a separate array, building an arg list with the contents of that array to pass to `print0` and then another one to pass to `printf` (and bash is bad at optimising this kind of thing), printing it to pipe which has to be done through an extra process, then `readarray` from the other end of the pipe reading that to fill up the target array. Compared to filling up the target array in the first place as the nameref approach would do, that is orders of magnitude less efficient.

Comment: I will stick to the `nameref` approach for outputting arrays.  I had been using `printf '%s\n' "$var"` to have the possibility to output a single string or a single numeric value that could be used in conditional statements.  There should be no complications returning a single string or a single numeric value (including a boolean), am I correct ?  For multiple value `nameref` looks as the sensible approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `done` at the end of your loop

```
#!/bin/bash

function my_function() {
  declare -n myarray="$1"
  local isufx=()
  
  for ext in "${myarray[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$ext" == "PROGL" ]]; then
      isufx+=( --include=\*.{rc,el,c,f} )
      (( vb >= 2 )) && echo " ext: $ext"
      continue
    elif [[ "$ext" == "PEXTD" ]]; then
      isufx+=( --include=\*.{rc,el,c,f} )
      isufx+=( --include=\*.{cp,cpp,f90,f95,f03,f08} )
      (( vb >= 2 )) && echo " ext: $ext"
      continue
    elif [[ "$ext" == "TYPOG" ]]; then
      isufx+=( --include=\*.{org,texi,tex} )
      (( vb >= 2 )) && echo " ext: $ext"
      continue
    fi
  done
  
  echo -e "${isufx[@]}"
}

my_include=("PROGL" "EMPTY" "PEXTD" "TYPOG" "NONAME")
my_function my_include

exit
```

Comment: Would there be any capability to input two or more arrays as input ?

Comment: You can append an array to another array and call the function or call the function x times, or do another loop and call the function with all needed arrays, don't get what you mean?

Comment: I mean this, using  `out=$( my_function "${this_array[@]}" "${that_array[@]}"`.

Comment: How would the namerefs for the two arrays look like?

Comment: ignoring bad practices like global variables, the only way to pass a value to a function in bash is via arguments. If you need to pass two arrays then you need some sort of marker (any value guaranteed **not** to be in either array) in between them so that you can iterate over `"$@"` and store the values in array "A" or array "B" (or even array "C", and so on) depending on whether they came before or after the marker. e.g. `myfunc "${a1[@]}" XXXXX "${a2[@]}" XXXXX "${a3[@]}"`  Or just use perl, where you can pass arrays by reference rather than by value.

Comment: Honey, hush!  Markers between arrays.  Fantastic plan.

Comment: Passing arrays through `nameref` is bad practice?

Comment: Reading arrays with a marker works well.  Still, one would have the problem about how to return an array.  Returning an array with a marker is problematic.

Comment: @cas  At any rate, isn't the solution by Stéphane Chazelas passing arrays by reference.  A solution that works well with array input and well as with array output.

Comment: No, passing arrays with nameref is good, and SC's code is clear, concise and well-written. Unfortunately, refs in bash kind of suck. It works but, like everything even slightly "advanced" in bash, using it tends to be ugly, complicated, overly verbose, and non-portable: "Lipstick on a pig". And still subject to the usual annoyances like word splitting and quoting requirements. Also, pretty much any time you need to do anything advanced in bash, you're going far beyond what shell is good at (coordinating the execution of other programs) and should be using a more suitable language instead.

Comment: SC's solution is good - great even, certainly better than my "markers" suggestion (i'd forgotten about bash namerefs because I don't use them - if i ever need something like that it means I should be writing in perl, not bash. Also most times you see them used, they're being used as a really bad clone of associative arrays) - but it's more of a demonstration that you *can* do something in bash if you really have to, rather than a demonstration that you *should*.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration.  I really needed it.

Comment: @cas It would be interesting to ask a question for a perl implementation if you are up for it.  What do you think?